# Leaflet.js display of a non-geo map (gdal2tiles.py) – I need a concrete example

Tags: leaflet

I'm displaying a map that's been tiled (`-p raster`) using `gdal2tiles.py`.  The X-coordinate is about [0..-1160].  The Y-coordinate, for some reason, is [-700,0].  Zoom-levels 0-5.

I simply *cannot* get a plausible display to work.  Sometimes, if I zoom-out to level-zero, I see the map way down at the bottom of the display ... not centered.  Nothing at all appears at other levels.

I am also seeing the display "bounce back and forth" between about a 3-o'clock and a 6-o'clock position.  (Only, once again, at zoom-level zero.)

I am *at my wit's end.*  Please give guidance.  *Complete* examples.  Anything ...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found my answer:

> If you're going to be using several layers in your Leaflet map, *add them in the constructor-call,* using the `layers` parameter.

If you try to do things with the layers before joining them all together, or with the map with no layers added, "strange and default things will happen."  (For example, although I requested the `Simple` CRS when constructing things (separately...), the net-effect was to actually try to use a different one.  Therefore, "do what the author expected."  Specify all the layers at once, to the Map constructor.  Then, customize them as you need to.  Make very sure that they all know about each other from the very start of things.